# how to break line after some characters using Eval in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
<div class="project-description" style="margin: 28px 0px;">
    <p ><%#Eval("Info").ToString()%> 

    </p>

</div>
```

and the output of above is:

> It's mundane to attempt on suits, dresses, trousers or shoes before
>   purchasing them. Individuals intuitively know they have to attempt on
>   garments to make sure they fit, feel great and are appealing on them.
>   Shouldn't we think about a home? It's most likely the most exorbitant
>   buy you'll ever make. Isn't it considerably more imperative to
>   "attempt on" a home before you buy it? What on earth do I mean? That
>   being said, its common to search for a home in places that are
>   advantageous to work and school.

now i want to break line after some some character . 
i want the output like below.:

> It's mundane to attempt on suits, dresses, trousers or shoes before
>   purchasing them. Individuals intuitively know they have to attempt on
>   garments to make sure they fit, feel great and are appealing on them.
>   Shouldn't we think about a home.
>
> It's most likely the most exorbitant buy you'll ever make. Isn't it
>   considerably more imperative to "attempt on" a home before you buy it?
>   What on earth do I mean.
>
> That being said, its common to search for a home in places that are
>   advantageous to work and school.

Comment: I guess you could put `<br/>` in your info value

Comment: I would specify width on p element instead and handle this rather via css. i.e.: <p style="width:200px">...</p>

Comment: <%# Eval("Info").ToString() %> /> no need for <p>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 1 public function on .CS side e.g. if you want to break line after every fullstop.

in .CS file

```
public string TrimString(string str)
{
    return str.Replace(".",".<br />");
}
```

.aspx file

```
<%#TrimString(Eval("Info").ToString())%>
```

Alternate solution is

```
<%#Eval("Info").ToString().Replace(".",".<br />") %>
```

if you want to add "." after 50 character and then 
 then

```
<%# Eval("Info").ToString().Length>50 ? Eval("Info").ToString().Substring(0,50)+Eval("Info").ToString().Substring(51).Replace(".",".<br />") : Eval("Info").ToString() %>
```

Comment: it gives output : Fully Furn

Comment: Instead of writing function on .cs file better option is to wirte Replace function with eval  <%#Eval("Info").ToString().Replace(".","<br />")%>

Comment: ok thank yoou ...its done..
but suppose i want output like : 1)Fully Furnished 12 units of 3 bedrooms with 2 full bathrooms, living, dining and kitchen provided with free telephone, internet, satellite connection, 24 hrs security and free maintenance. 
2)The building has a common swimming pool with BBQ party area & gym on the roof top. 
then how to do?

Comment: if i want to find "." after 50 characters and then put <br/> then how to do ?

Comment: Added in my answer if you want add "." after 50 character. Does that resolve your problem?

Comment: Check updated solutions now for the last solution which I've updated in my answer. Does that work?

Comment: FYI - this solution only work for first 50 character. If you want to split your string after every 50 character then this will not work

Comment: Now last solution will work even if the characters in Info field is less than 50 or more than 50, it'll meet your requirements. Hope this will help and you can vote up for my answer. :)

Comment: Any specific pattern in your updated expected output? I can't find any specific pattern.

Comment: Seems like spamming, after providing answer, you changed the question and vote down for the answer provided.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you add line breaks to your descriptions and store them with the line breaks, if they aren't already.

Then when you output the text to the browser, set your container `<div>` so that it adhers to the line breaks using the CSS propery `white-space`

```
div.project-description { white-space: pre-wrap; }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to break a line after dot (.) then use below code

```
<%#Eval("Info").ToString().Replace(".",".<br />")%>
```

it will replace "." with new line

Comment: ok thank yoou ...its done.. but suppose i want output like : 1)Fully Furnished 12 units of 3 bedrooms with 2 full bathrooms, living, dining and kitchen provided with free telephone, internet, satellite connection, 24 hrs security and free maintenance. 2)The building has a common swimming pool with BBQ party area & gym on the roof top. then how to do?

Comment: if i want to find "." after 50 characters and then put <br/> then how to do ?

Comment: @Jay Replace() function replace all occurance of character/string with new character/string. so this function replace "<br />" if "." occure after 50 char or 100 char

Comment: but i want to do fix after 50 chars...because i have long text with "."  but i want <br/> after 50 charcters.

Comment: Making your code produce a new line on a `.` seems like a very mickey mouse way of doing things.

Comment: i ahve edit my expected output...can you please help me in that

Comment: still unclear with your expecatation. Do you wnat to split string after x character or to split string on specific character occurance? however, if you want to show your string in multiline in specic area then use @Coulton solution.

Comment: i want by split string after x character

Comment: suppose my string is :- hello.i am fine. thank you.
so i want output like - hello.
i am fine.
thank you.
each sentence after . in new line..